# проверка событие на элементе

Tags: javascript, html

на сайте много js скриптов. как проверить какие функции и из каких js файлов повешены на на событие html элементе?

Answer (score 1):

В хроме если ткнуть на нужный элемент правой кнопкой и выбрать Inspect, то в появившемся окне остается только ткнуть во вкладку Event Listeners и будет там список всего, что на этот элемент навешано (галочка Ancestors по желанию, чтобы отсечь ивенты не самого элемента). В FF в принципе все тоже самое есть, даже вроде в самом списке dom элементов было встроено.

Comment: неужели у кого-то хром на инглише?

Comment: @Jean-Claude безотносительно моего места пребывания, разработка вообще и особенно работа с linux довольно быстро учит пользовать англ. версии всего, что можно. Потому что любую проблему/ошибку на англ. я просто скопи-пасчу и влет загуглю, с русскими сообщениями меня ожидают одиночество, боль и страдания)